# Use Exchange Web Services on Android

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

there is a microsoft API for Java to connect to Micrsoft Exchange Webservices. Unfortunately it doesn't work on Android as mentioned in the Microsoft tutorial.

Has anybody an idea how to connect to Microsoft Exchange with Android? There is a solution using WebDav, but WebDav is only supported by Microsoft up to Exchange 2007.

Can anybody help me?

thx

Eddy

Comment: Answered for the same prob here [Jweb services for android][1]. Check if it can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376305/exchange-web-services-on-android-error/18957286#18957286

Answer (score 1):

You can use microsoft's EWS api which is open source for android by doing the following steps,

1. Download the source code available in the URL,
   **http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi
   EWSJavaAPI_1.1.5.zip**
2. Make the changes to above api to work for JDK 1.4 in eclipse like remove override annotations etc
3. Download source code of `javax.*` package available in below URL,
   **http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsr17310srcjar.htm
   jsr173_1.0_src.jar.zip**
4. Download source code of stax api available in below URL,
   **http://dist.codehaus.org/stax/distributions
   stax-src-1.2.0.zip**
5. Keep all the sources under the single java project in eclipse
6. Open the project explorer and select the package which are starts with "**javax**" and rename to your company name eg: **com**. *Note:* Eclipse will ask for all the naming contexts will change then click OK.
7. Export all the java sources to one single jar file.

You are good now to go to use the jar in Android application with out any problems.

I used the same way explained above and it worked in android application 100% perfectly.

Comment: are these steps complete ? i followed the same but didnt work.

Comment: i got EWSJava1.2 compiled with all libraries like stated above, but when used in my project i got runtime error:
E/dalvikvm(4626): Could not find class 'microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.XMLNodeType', referenced from method microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.AutodiscoverService.getLegacyUserSettingsAtUrl

i tried every combination of the library references, classpath etc.
i think it is related to the httpclient versions issue.

any advise or a ready to use jar will be great.

Answer (score -2):

There is a JAVA version of the EWS Managed API. Perhaps you can use that as a starting point.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi.