# Exchange Web Services on Android, error

Tags: java, android, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to implement and use Exchange Web Services on Android. I found this post and I proceed the same way by installing the Microsoft's EWS API JAVA:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476055/use-exchange-web-services-on-android
```

I wrote and executed a simple sample that sends a message. But I obtained this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeServiceBase
```

May anybody help me? Is there any sample anybody might share?
Thanks!

This is the sample:

```
    package com.example.ewsandroid;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Locale;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

        final Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
                try {
                    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
                    WebCredentials webCredentials = new WebCredentials(
                            "sample@gmail.com",
                            "sample");
                    URI url = new URI("https://sample.sample.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
                    service.setCredentials(webCredentials);
                    service.setUrl(url);

                    EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
                    msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
                    msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText
                               ("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
                    msg.getToRecipients().add("sample@gmail.com");
                    msg.send();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

I'm using Android 2.2 as Platform, Java Compiler 1.6

Comment: What's the sample that gave the error?

Comment: It's in the body of the message.

Answer (score 1):

There's a commercial ActiveSync library available @ [JWebServices for java and android](http://www.independentsoft.de/). Download JWebServices for Exchange in that page. Once you download , Just add jwebservices-1.1.jar jar file to ur project and u just have to provide the info while creating the Service object in ur code, as shown below. It worked in my android app.

`Service service = new Service(
                        "https://mail.yourdomain.com/ews/Exchange.asmx",
                        "emailid@yourdomain.com", "password");`

Here is the example code to display the appointments between current time and next 12 hours.

```
Service service = new Service(
                    "https://mail.yourdomain.com/ews/Exchange.asmx",
                    "emailid@yourdomain.com", "password");
            Date startDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Date endDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

            CharSequence startTime = DateFormat.format(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", startDate);

            CharSequence endTime = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    endDate);

            IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo restriction1 = new IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(
                    AppointmentPropertyPath.START_TIME,
                    startTime.toString());
            IsLessThanOrEqualTo restriction2 = new IsLessThanOrEqualTo(
                    AppointmentPropertyPath.END_TIME, endTime.toString());
            And restriction3 = new And(restriction1, restriction2);

            FindItemResponse response = service.findItem(
                    StandardFolder.CALENDAR,
                    AppointmentPropertyPath.getAllPropertyPaths(),
                    restriction3);
            int numberOfItems = response.getItems().size();
            if (numberOfItems <= 0)
                Log.v(">>><<<<", "There are no Appointments..");
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
                if (response.getItems().get(i) instanceof Appointment) {
                    Appointment appointment = (Appointment) response
                            .getItems().get(i);
                    String logicalRoomName = null, location = appointment
                            .getLocation();
                    Log.v(">>><<<<", "Location = " + location);
                    Log.v(">>><<<<",
                            "Subject = " + appointment.getSubject());
                    Log.v(">>><<<<",
                            "StartTime = " + appointment.getStartTime());
                    Log.v(">>><<<<",
                            "EndTime = " + appointment.getEndTime());
                    Log.v(">>><<<<",
                            "Body Preview = "
                                    + appointment.getBodyPlainText()); } }
```

Comment: Hi. This seems to be good alternative. But unfortunately my trial version was working for only one day and I am getting a message saying that I need to contact the team to get an extended evaluation version when I compile. Did you get thru any such things? any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Mr.Andro Selva. As I mentioned its a commercial library. So, its better to use this, when you absolutely need it(Say ur company pays on ur behalf :P).

Comment: thanks for the response Shiv.. Actually I did contact the team and they helped me with the issue and it works now.. But anyways as you said, we could make use of this excellent library only if the company is ready to pay!! fingers crossed :D